# Web links are opened inside the application

Tags: hyperlinks

For a long time I have been bothered that whenever you click an web link inside an application e.g. stackexchange, it opens the url inside the application. Instead of using my installed web browser e.g. chrome. Is there a way to force apps to open links in chrome and not inside the application itself?

Comment: Just for clarification: do you have SE app installed?

Comment: Yes (comment need to certain number of characters) @AndrewT.

Answer (score 1):

[Chromer Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=arun.com.chromer) does this - screenshot below shows link from XDA app opened in Chromer (it has pretty good reviews from Android Authority and others )

> ... achieved by use of Chrome Custom Tabs which are lightweight browser tabs from Google Chrome (limited other browsers are supported too).
>
> Chromer slides over the website from the app, enabling you to transition into the website seamlessly. Even if you navigate multiple times, you can always press X to quickly return to the app, where you left.

While it is not exactly the same as opening in Chrome, it pretty much is the same with all normal browser functions. Ease of returning to app is noteworthy

[image]

How to use?

Set Chromer as the default browser in your phone. From there on, any link you try to open in your phone will be presented in a custom tab. You can also not do this and choose to open link in Chromer when prompted.

Comment: Do I only need to install it, and that's it?

Comment: Tried it, but wouldn't consider it a solution (at least not for me). It didn't support all apps I use. Hence I just click in theupper right corner choose, open in chrome on the "in-application-browser".

Comment: Yes, I did. It worked well with links in stackexchange. But one other app I tried (youtube link) I didn't open in Chromer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62333/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-olba12).

Comment: I don't think it was YouTube itself which was a problem. I think it was the app, that I was opening the link from.

Answer (score 0):

Most Apps have an internal setting, usually buried in a deep non obvious place, that controls if the in app or system browser is used.
The default is usually to use the in app browser.
You have to find this setting in each app and change it.

Chromer is a nice way to manage links opened from other apps (Web Heads) but AFAIK has no control over if other apps use it.

If somebody knows a one shot method to change the browser settin for all app I am all ears.

Comment: What can I do if the app does not have such a setting? I want that the app passes the URL to open to the default browser!