# Open unlinked URL in corresponding app

Tags: applications

How to open a link in an app if it's not available as a link but as a text, and it can't be opened in the app itself? Is there e.g. some app that can get link pasted from a clipboard and open it?

Example: I have a link to a YouTube video on a web page *as a text* and want to open it in YouTube app.

Comment: Please provide an example of that

Comment: @beeshyams you have a link to youtube video on a web page as text and want to open it in app

Comment: See this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.derkydapps.copyurl

Comment: @beeshyams that's not what i need

Comment: I am not sure but try the app mentioned here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179572/131553

Answer (score 1):

Any regular web browser including the default ROM one should be able to do this natively, provided you have said app set as default for that type of link. Unless I misunderstand what you mean.

Just copy the link text from wherever and paste it in the address bar of a (new) tab. If a default application has been set for this type of link it should redirect it there automatically.

Comment: +1, unless we both misunderstood the question.

Comment: All http links are opened in the browser itself.

Comment: Just tested here in my phone and opening a YouTube link pasted in the browser address bar successfully opened it in the corresponding YouTube app, so if this doesn't happen in your case either the app is not set as default, or there is something else interfering with your ROM, app, or settings

Comment: Well, I have Silk Browser. I cannot even find the settings for associations for it.

Comment: Settings are at system level, not in the browser preferences

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos associations are under Settings - All Applications - %appname%, right? But Silk Browser is not listed there.

Comment: @SmitJohnth select the corresponding app you want the link to be opened in; e.g. in this case: YouTube, not the browser. Then select *Open by default*. Check the value of **Open supported links** and change it if necessary.

Comment: @AndrewT. any screenshots?